# Sql query to Left Join in Linq to entity

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I've below `SQL` query

```
Select LC.*,LP.[LandingPageName] from [LandingPageCompanies] LC
 Left join [LandingPageContent] LP on LP.SubCategoryID=LC.SubCategoryID
 where  LC.[CategoryID]=17
```

And i need to convert it into `LINQ to entity`.

i've tried the following query, But it's working as `Inner join`

```
 var data = (from t1 in dbSavingContainer.LandingPageCompanies
                        join t2 in dbSavingContainer.LandingPageContents on t1.SubCategoryID equals t2.SubCategoryID
                        where t1.CategoryID == CategoryID
                        select new
                        {
                            CategoryID = t1.CategoryID,
                            CompanyID = t1.CompanyID,
                            CompanyLink = t1.CompanyLink,
                            CompanyLogo = t1.CompanyLogo,
                            CompanyName = t1.CompanyName,
                            SubCategoryID = t1.SubCategoryID,
                            LandingPageName = t2.LandingPageName
                        }).ToList();
```

Where i'm lacking. ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks..i just solved it using below query ;)

```
 var data = (from t1 in dbSavingContainer.LandingPageCompanies
             join t2 in dbSavingContainer.LandingPageContents on t1.SubCategoryID equals t2.SubCategoryID
             into x from y in x.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   where t1.CategoryID == CategoryID
                     select new
                      {
                        CategoryID = t1.CategoryID,
                        CompanyID = t1.CompanyID,
                        CompanyLink = t1.CompanyLink,
                        CompanyLogo = t1.CompanyLogo,
                        CompanyName = t1.CompanyName,
                        SubCategoryID = t1.SubCategoryID,
                        LandingPageName = y.LandingPageName
                    }).ToList();
```